# $z$- score probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The proportion of people who like playing basketball is 2%, so a
> student randomly sample 1000, but find the proportion is 4%, if the
> true proportion is 2%. What the probability that this student detect
> at least 4% in random sample?

I used the formula, but found the $z$ score is $4.51$ which is impossible I think.

Comment: Your $z$-score looks correct to me, but why do you say it is impossible? Certainly the $p$-value is very small, and the null hypothesis that the true proportion is 2% would be rejected at the 1% (or even 0.1% or 0.001%) confidence level.

Answer (score 1):

Your z-score is correct. We are conducting a test on a sample proportion, so the zscore under the hypotheses

$$H_0:p=.02\\
H_A:p>.02$$

is

$$\frac{\hat p-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}=\frac{.04-.02}{\sqrt{\frac{.02(.98)}{1000}}}\\
=4.517$$

This is indeed a high zscore, but it's not impossible. You might think it is strange because most tables in books don't have z score that go this high in the tables. It's true. You must use a computer program if your table doesn't carry z scores this high, or you could just report the probability as "approximately zero" should also be fine. The probability of detecting at least .04/getting a zscore of at least 4.517 is

```
> 1-pnorm(4.517)
[1] 3.136095e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to testing [and there is nothing wrong with showing that, as in @stacker's Answer (+1)], but the fundamental problem is to find $$P(X \ge 40) = 1 - P(X \le 39)= 0.000043,$$ when
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p=0.02),$
The exact value (nearly $0)$ can be found using R, where 'pbinom'
is a binomial CDF:

```
1 - pbinom(39, 1000, .02)
[1] 4.339876e-05
```

This is indeed a very unlikely outcome. With proportion $p = 0.02$ who like to play basketball, it is very likely
that there will be *fewer than 31 in a random sample of 1000* is over 99%. [The code 'qbinom' is a binomial quantile function (inverse CDF).]

```
qbinom(.99, 1000, .02)
[1] 31
pbinom(31, 1000, .02)
[1] 0.992492
```

The plot below shows the two binomial distributions.

[image]

R code for figure above:

```
x = 0:60;  pdf.02 = dbinom(x, 1000, .02)
pdf.04 = dbinom(x, 1000, .04)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(1000,p); p=.02 [bars], p-.04 [dots]"
plot(x, pdf.02, type="h", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
 points(x, pdf.04, pch=19, col="red")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

*Note:* If you try to use a normal approximation, you will get an answer to the main problem that is very nearly $0,$ but your z-score will be far beyond
the values usually included in printed normal CDF tables.

```
z = 20/sqrt(1000*.02*.98);  z
[1] 4.51754
1 - pnorm(z)
[1] 3.128118e-06  # 0.00000313
```